# sum of all rows when specific column is equal -data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, if-statement

```
df
  var1 var2  var3
1    a    1  0.5
2    b    2  5
3    a    3  12
4    c    6  0
5    d   88  0
6    b    0  0

df2
  var1 var2  var3
1  k    1    0.5
2  l    0.6  5
3  k    3    12
4  k    6    0
5  v   12    0


> list <- list(df,df2)

for(i in list){
   i %>% 
  group_by(var1) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(var1))
}
```

Whenever `var1` is equal, I want the rest of the rows to be summed up, and this would be the new row. I want that the list of `data.frames` only contains `data.frames` that have unique rows, but the columns should add up. I have the loop from here [sum of rows when condition is met- data.frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62305258/sum-of-rows-when-condition-is-met-data-frame-in-r) , but I was not statisfied with the answers.

The result should look like this

```
df
  var1 var2  var3
1    a    4  12.5
2    b    2  5
4    c    6  0
5    d   88  0

df2
  var1 var2  var3
1  k    10    12.5
2  l    0.6  5
3  v   12    0
```

my real list contains a lot `data.frames` with a lot of rows and columns.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Tidy-version:

```
df <- read.table(text = "var1 var2  var3
1    a    1  0.5
2    b    2  5
3    a    3  12
4    c    6  0
5    d   88  0
6    b    0  0", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "var1 var2  var3
1  k    1    0.5
2  l    0.6  5
3  k    3    12
4  k    6    0
5  v   12    0", strings = F, header = T)


l <- list(df = df, df2 = df2) # please use other name than "list"

library(tidyverse)

l <- map(l, ~.x %>%
         group_by(var1) %>%
         summarise_all(list(sum)) %>%
         ungroup())

l

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# var1   var2  var3
# <chr> <int> <dbl>
#   1 a         4  12.5
# 2 b         2   5  
# 3 c         6   0  
# 4 d        88   0  
# 
# $df2
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# var1   var2  var3
# <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#   1 k      10    12.5
# 2 l       0.6   5  
# 3 v      12     0
```

Comment: Using `dplyr 1.0.0` you could use `across()`: `summarise(across(num_range("var", 2:3), sum), .groups="drop_last")`

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine, you just need to put it in a function and use `lapply`. Here I've used data.table, but you could also put that dplyr code in a function and use that as the second argument to `lapply`.

```
library(data.table)
lapply(mylist, function(df) setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), var1])
```

Answer (score 0):

In *base* you can use `aggregate` in `lapply` to sum up per group.

```
lapply(list, function(x) aggregate(.~var1, x, sum))
#lapply(list, function(x) aggregate(x[,-1], as.list(x[1]), sum)) #Alternative
#[[1]]
#  var1 var2 var3
#1    a    4 12.5
#2    b    2  5.0
#3    c    6  0.0
#4    d   88  0.0
#
#[[2]]
#  var1 var2 var3
#1    k 10.0 12.5
#2    l  0.6  5.0
#3    v 12.0  0.0
```

or using `rowsum` with groups in the rownames:

```
lapply(list, function(x) rowsum(x[,-1], x[,1]))
```